# Are X and Y homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Let X=(0,1) in R and Y=(3,23) in R be equipped with the subspace topology of (R, Teuclidean). Are X and Y homeomorphic?

I am not too sure where to go with this, I was trying to follow an example in Topology Without Tears but I don't really understand why it is doing what it is doing.

So, so far I have;

*Let (3,23) in R with 3<23, and consider the function f: (0,1) -> (3,23) given by 
f(x)=3(1-x)+23x.*

But I don't know what that is about or how to progress further.
Thanks

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? Is it bijective? If so, is the inverse continuous?

Answer (score 1):

You can always match two intervals one on top of the other linearly.
If $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are two intervals then

$$ f(t) = \frac{c-d}{a-b}t + c - a\frac{c-d}{a-b}$$
gives such a transformation.
Note that $f$ is automatically continuous (for example because it's differentiable).

Let's check what happens in your example: $(a,b) = (0,1)$ and $(c,d) = (3,23)$
so the corresponding $f$ is
$$ f(t) = -20t + 3 = 3(1-t) + 23t.$$

What's left to check that it is a homeomorphism is that it is bijective with continuous inverse.

Let's apply the formula above but this time with $(a,b) = (3,23)$, $(c,d)=(0,1)$.
We have
$$ g(s) = \frac{-1}{-20}s-3\frac{-1}{-20} =\frac{1}{20}\left( s - 3 \right).$$

If we can show that $g$ is the inverse of $f$ then we are done.
To show that, one needs to prove both $g(f(t))=t$ and $f(g(s))$.
This can be done simply by plugging in.

The same argument shows that any two intervals are homemorphic provided they are of the same kind (open, closed, semi-open). To be pedantic, to show that $[a,b)$ is homeomorphic to $(c,d]$ one needs to tweak our transformations so that they have negative linear part.

Comment: is there any relevance to it being the euclidean topology?

Comment: yes. essentially continuous for euclidean topology iff $\epsilon-\delta$ continuous. This is really straightforward from the definitions. To prove the function $f$ up there is continuous we can use the following: the identity is continuous; constant maps are continuous; products, sums and compositions of continuous functions are continuos.

Answer (score 0):

Two spaces are homeomorphic (by definition) if there is a continuous, bijective function $f$ between them, such that the inverse is also continuous and bijective.

So this problem has already proposed such a map, and it remains to show that it is continuous and bijective, and then, after writing down the inverse, showing that this is continuous and bijective also.

So you have $6$ things to prove, and $1$ thing to calculate:

(1) $f$ is continuous

(2) if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$

(3) for every $y \in (3,23)$, there is an $x \in (0,1)$ so that $f(x) = y$

Calculate the inverse (one way is to write $y = 3(1-x) + 23x$, then solve for $x$), then prove (1)-(3) for it (with the statements modified as appropriate)

Comment: I havent done real analysis for three years, how do I show that f is continuous? using an epsilon delta argument?

Comment: If you are convinced you *could* write the epsilon-delta proof, I would skip it and just claim the function is obviously continuous (it is just a linear function). If it's been a while, it might be instructive to quickly write (or at least sketch) the epsilon-delta proof.

Comment: I am required to prove all my answers so I would probably have to prove that f is continuous, but my epsilon delta proof is not working.

Comment: First simplify the function: $f(x) = 3 + 20x$. Now, take any $\epsilon >0$, and take $\delta < \dfrac{1}{20}\epsilon$. You'll have $|f(x_2) - f(x_1)| = |20x_2 - 20x_1| = 20|x_2 - x_1|$. For a general linear function $f(x) = ax + b$, take $\delta < \dfrac{1}{a}\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much! what is your opinion on the solution below? I think I follow it better, but does it show the (1)-(3) as required?

Comment: No, it does not explicitly demonstrate any of those properties (though it does explicitly calculate the correct inverse). It is still a good answer, because it gets at the intuition behind *what is actually happening*, but for instance, it still claims $f$ is continuous rather than proving it.

Comment: Just roll up your sleeves and go for it. Injectivity: if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, this means $3+20x_1 = 3 + 20x_2$. Subtract $3$ from both sides, divide by $20$, this shows $x_1 = x_2$. Injectivity is demonstrated.

Comment: how would i show (3) for every y∈(3,23), there is an x∈(0,1) so that f(x)=y

Comment: also, in my notes there is a fourth condition that, for each V in the Topology T f(V) is in T, so this is closure? how do i show this?

Comment: Pick any $y \in (3,23)$. We want to find an $x$ so that $f(x) = y$. Just write out $f(x)$, solve for $x$, and show that it is between $0$ and $1$ as long as $y$ was between $3$ and $23$. Note that $20x = (y-3) \in (0,20)$, so $x = \dfrac{1}{20}(y-3) \in (0,1)$ is a solution.